# Why does the gradle commandline do not show specs2 results?

Tags: java, scala, gradle, specs2, scalacheck

I have a scala project which contains specs2 scalacheck specifications for a java project.

I am able to run the specs with the JUnitRunner in eclipse and all test pass.

I can also execute the gradle test task but I do not see any console output regarding the tests.

this is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

ext {
    scalaVersion                  = "2.11.+"
    specs2ScalaVersion            = "2.11"
    specs2ScalacheckVersion       = "3.1.1"
    dependencyJunit               = "junit:junit:4.+"
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'camm-shared specs',
                   'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases" }
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:$scalaVersion"
    compile files('../lib/MarketInterface.jar')
    compile project(':camm-shared')

    testCompile "org.specs2:specs2-core_$specs2ScalaVersion:$specs2ScalacheckVersion"
    testCompile "org.specs2:specs2-scalacheck_$specs2ScalaVersion:$specs2ScalacheckVersion"
    testCompile "org.specs2:specs2-junit_$specs2ScalaVersion:$specs2ScalacheckVersion"
    testCompile dependencyJunit
}

test {
  //makes the standard streams (err and out) visible at console when running tests
  testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}

test {
  onOutput { descriptor, event ->
    logger.lifecycle("Test: " + descriptor + " produced standard out/err: " + event.message )
  }
}
```

I have already tried to suggestions to get the console output by configuring the test task but that did not solve the problem.

When I clean the project and run the test task, it takes app. 20 seconds, so it probably runs all the test, which do not fail. They JUnitRunner in eclipse also takes around 20 seconds - I have `minTestOk = 100000`.

Comment: Did you figure out how to get this working? I've decorated my test classes with the @RuNWith, and so on, but still don't see any output.

Answer (score 4):

Gradle (currently) does not recognise Specs2 tests automatically, and therefore does not run them out-of-the-box. If you want Gradle to run your Specs2 tests, you must either decorate your test classes with JUnit's `@RunWith` annotation or write a specified task for it. Both options [are explained in the official Specs2 documentation](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.0/org.specs2.guide.OtherBuildTools.html).

Comment: 404 on link in this answer.

Comment: working link: https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.6.6/org.specs2.guide.OtherBuildTools.html

Comment: Still not working, is that doc obsolete? What junit & specs versions are supported?